# Email validation - is filter_var enough nowadays?

Tags: php, validation, email

I was wondering if filering emails using filter_var is still enough nowadays, since I've heard that there are ways to work around this filter.

Current code:

```
if (!filter_var($emailaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$errormsg = "Invalid email address"; 
}
```

Do you think it's enough (security-wise)? are there any better ways to make sure the user inputs a valid email? I'm not really sure if I'm going to require email verification on registeration, planning to use emails mostly for password recovery and keep them hashed.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah definitely. it is more than enough.

Comment: don't forget a "valid" email doesn't mean that the email will transmit a message to the user.  the only way to be sure of that is to send them an email and have them follow a link back for verification.

Comment: Of course, this filter is supposed to make sure people do not get to insert unwanted things into the email row in the DB.

Comment: You guys have any idea on how to prevent weird emails getting through the filter? things like "email@[123.123.123.123]" still work with the filter_validate_email function.